# Project database upgrade using ant to upgrade the database

Tags: database, ant

I am currently working on two web projects both which use Ant to upgrade the database.
Each web project has its own build.properties file for upgrading the database using ant.
Each separate build.properties file is used to log on to two different databases for the two specific servers as obvious.

How do I set up the ANT_HOME to be used for the database upgrades for both the projects? 
As currently I have to change the ANT_HOME to point to the first project when I want to perform a database upgrade on the first project and then for the second one when working on the second project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ANT_HOME variable is used to indicate where you have insalled ANT. You should not need to reset the variable in order to build different projects, unless for some reason each project requires a different version of ANT (Unlikely).

When you call ant it normally looks for a build file called "build.xml" in the local directory. To call ANT on a different project, use the "-f" parameter:

```
ant -f /path/to/project1/build.xml
ant -f /path/to/project2/build.xml
```

By default, each project will look for other files relative to the build.xml file.